# Memory card is not working .!

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

I have bought Sandisk 32 GB MicroSD class 10 for my Lenovo Phab Plus . I am facing a problem . Card is need to be format Everytime I insert it after I connect it with my PC . It's working fine in PC , I have a old phone which even does not have  JAVA , It is working in that phone also. Sometimes it is not detectable .
[image]

When I re-inserted it I found this .

[image]

What should I do ?? I've already  replaced memory card once from Amazon . But same problem .
Moreover My device does not show as Media Device on my PC .  When I was using 8 GB SD card , it used to connect as Moung SD Card but now its not working .

Comment: Did you try formatting using your Android device?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that , Since I don't have wifi here . After formatting this device.It does not start without wifi connection . I am going home tomorrow then I will try to format it .

Comment: I meant formatting the **card** in your device

Comment: Yep I did earlier several times . But as soon as insert it after transferring files from my PC , it starts to ask for format .

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed if the device supports a 32gb memory card, try using an 8gb memory card, if it persist, you might need to do a backup and then a factory reset.